# unable to codesign using identities in this team no private keys available error in orgnizer of xcode ,how to resolve?

Tags: iphone, code-signing-certificate, xcode-organizer

I am using xcode 4.5.1 i have created csr,cer and provisioning profile files, but when i drag provisioning profile file to xcode it gives error "unable to codesign using identities in this team no private keys available." and "valid singning identity not found."
Any help appreciated.

Thanks,
Madhuri

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need to this manually.

If you go the Xcode Organiser:

- select de first tab (devices)
- select team > your name
- Hit refresh (bottom right)

repeat the same operation for the provisioning profile and XCode will install all the development assets you need to get started.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you do not have the keys corresponding to the certificates in your keychain.Export and install the private key to the keychain and try again

Comment: i already check that it is present, but still it is giving error,I have created CSR file using keychain access at that time 2 keys are generated private & public and private key has expanded icon when i am expanding it, it showing me certificate.